# How take a specific element on HTML site for webscarping

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm doing a scrap on this [site](https://www2.camara.leg.br/atividade-legislativa/legislacao/Constituicoes_Brasileiras/constituicao-cidada/constituintes/parlamentaresconstituintes/senadores-constituintes)

I want the names and the information in front of the name. The scrap with the name worked, the html element is ".external-link". But I can't scrap the information in front of it.

See the image: the yellow circle is what worked, the red circle is the information that I can scrap and didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```r
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
h <- read_html("https://www2.camara.leg.br/atividade-legislativa/legislacao/Constituicoes_Brasileiras/constituicao-cidada/constituintes/parlamentaresconstituintes/senadores-constituintes")

after <- h %>% 
  html_element("#content-core") %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  str_split("\\d+\\.", simplify = TRUE) %>% 
  t() %>% 
  gsub("\\n*", "", .)

names <- h %>% 
  html_elements("#content-core a") %>% 
  html_text()
cbind(names, after[-1])
#>       names                      
#>  [1,] "AFFONSO ARINOS"           
#>  [2,] "AFFONSO CAMARGO"          
#>  [3,] "AFONSO SANCHO"            
#>  [4,] "ALBANO FRANCO"            
#>  [5,] "ALEXANDRE COSTA"          
#>  [6,] "ALFREDO CAMPOS"           
#>  [7,] "ALMIR GABRIEL"            
#>  [8,] "ALUÍSIO BEZERRA"          
#>  [9,] "ALVARO DIAS"              
#> [10,] "ÁLVARO PACHECO"           
#> [11,] "ANTÔNIO FARIAS"           
#> [12,] "ÁUREO DE MELLO"           
#> [13,] "CARLOS ALBERTO"           
#> [14,] "CARLOS ALBERTO DE'CARLI"  
#> [15,] "CARLOS CHIARELLI"         
#> [16,] "CHAGAS RODRIGUES"         
#> [17,] "CID SABÓIA DE CARVALHO"   
#> [18,] "DIRCEU CARNEIRO"          
#> [19,] "DIVALDO SURUAGY"          
#> [20,] "EDISON LOBÃO"             
#> [21,] "FÁBIO LUCENA"             
#> [22,] "FERNANDO HENRIQUE CARDOSO"
#> [23,] "FRANCISCO ROLLEMBERG"     
#> [24,] "GERSON CAMATA"            
#> [25,] "GUILHERME PALMEIRA"       
#> [26,] "HELIO GUEIROS"            
#> [27,] "HUGO NAPOLEÃO"            
#> [28,] "HUMBERTO LUCENA"          
#> [29,] "IRAM SARAIVA"             
#> [30,] "IRAPUAM COSTA JUNIOR "    
#> [31,] "ITAMAR FRANCO"            
#> [32,] "IVAN BONATO"              
#> [33,] "JAMIL HADDAD"             
#> [34,] "JARBAS PASSARINHO"        
#> [35,] "JOÃO CALMON"              
#> [36,] "JOÃO CASTELO"             
#> [37,] "JOÃO LOBO"                
#> [38,] "JOÃO MENEZES"             
#> [39,] "JORGE BORNHAUSEN"         
#> [40,] "JOSÉ AGRIPINO"            
#> [41,] "JOSÉ FOGAÇA"              
#> [42,] "JOSÉ IGNÁCIO FERREIRA"    
#> [43,] "JOSÉ PAULO BISOL"         
#> [44,] "JOSÉ RICHA"               
#> [45,] "JUTAHY MAGALHÃES"         
#> [46,] "LAVOISIER MAIA"           
#> [47,] "LEITE CHAVES"             
#> [48,] "LEOPOLDO PERES"           
#> [49,] "LOUREMBERG NUNES ROCHA"   
#> [50,] "LOURIVAL BAPTISTA"        
#> [51,] "LUIZ VIANA"               
#> [52,] "MANSUETO DE LAVOR"        
#> [53,] "MARCELO MIRANDA"          
#> [54,] "MARCIO LACERDA"           
#> [55,] "MARCO MACIEL"             
#> [56,] "MARCONDES GADELHA"        
#> [57,] "MÁRIO COVAS"              
#> [58,] "MÁRIO MAIA"               
#> [59,] "MAURÍCIO CORRÊA"          
#> [60,] "MAURO BENEVIDES"          
#> [61,] "MAURO BORGES"             
#> [62,] "MEIRA FILHO"              
#> [63,] "MENDES CANALE"            
#> [64,] "NABOR JÚNIOR"             
#> [65,] "NELSON CARNEIRO"          
#> [66,] "NELSON WEDEKIN"           
#> [67,] "NEY MARANHÃO"             
#> [68,] "NIVALDO MACHADO"          
#> [69,] "ODACIR SOARES"            
#> [70,] "OLAVO PIRES"              
#> [71,] "POMPEU DE SOUZA"          
#> [72,] "RACHID SALDANHA DERZI"    
#> [73,] "RAIMUNDO LIRA"            
#> [74,] "ROBERTO CAMPOS"           
#> [75,] "RONALDO ARAGÃO"           
#> [76,] "RONAN TITO"               
#> [77,] "RUY BACELAR"              
#> [78,] "SEVERO GOMES"             
#> [79,] "TEOTÔNIO VILELA FILHO"    
#> [80,] "VIRGÍLIO TÁVORA"          
#> [81,] "WILSON MARTINS"           
#>                                                                                                                   
#>  [1,] " AFFONSO ARINOS - PFL/RJ (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                           
#>  [2,] " AFFONSO CAMARGO - PMDB/PR (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                         
#>  [3,] " AFONSO SANCHO - PDS /CE (Ano de eleição: 1982)"                                                           
#>  [4,] " ALBANO FRANCO - PSDB/SE (Ano de eleição: 1982)"                                                           
#>  [5,] " ALEXANDRE COSTA - PFL/MA (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                          
#>  [6,] " ALFREDO CAMPOS - PMDB/MG (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                          
#>  [7,] " ALMIR GABRIEL - PMDB/PA (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                           
#>  [8,] " ALUÍSIO BEZERRA - PMDB/AC (Ano de eleição: 1986) "                                                        
#>  [9,] " ALVARO DIAS - PMDB/PR (Ano de eleição: 1982)"                                                             
#> [10,] " ÁLVARO PACHECO - PFL / PI (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                         
#> [11,] " ANTÔNIO FARIAS - PMB/PE (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                           
#> [12,] " ÁUREO DE MELLO - PMDB/AM (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                          
#> [13,] " CARLOS ALBERTO - PTB/RN (Ano de eleição: 1982)"                                                           
#> [14,] " CARLOS ALBERTO DE'CARLI - PMDB/AM (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                 
#> [15,] " CARLOS CHIARELLI - PFL /RS (Ano de eleição: 1982)"                                                        
#> [16,] " CHAGAS RODRIGUES - PSDB / PI (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                      
#> [17,] " CID SABÓIA DE CARVALHO - PMDB/CE (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                  
#> [18,] " DIRCEU CARNEIRO - PMDB/SC (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                         
#> [19,] " DIVALDO SURUAGY - PFL/AL (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                          
#> [20,] " EDISON LOBÃO - PFL/MA (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                             
#> [21,] " FÁBIO LUCENA - PMDB/AM (Ano de eleição: 1982)"                                                            
#> [22,] " FERNANDO HENRIQUE CARDOSO - PMDB/SP (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                               
#> [23,] " FRANCISCO ROLLEMBERG - PMDB/SE (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                    
#> [24,] " GERSON CAMATA - PMDB/ES (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                           
#> [25,] " GUILHERME PALMEIRA - PFL/AL (Ano de eleição: 1982)"                                                       
#> [26,] " HELIO GUEIROS - PMDB/PA (Ano de eleição: 1982)"                                                           
#> [27,] " HUGO NAPOLEÃO - PFL / PI (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                          
#> [28,] " HUMBERTO LUCENA - PMDB/PB (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                         
#> [29,] " IRAM SARAIVA - PMDB/GO (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                            
#> [30,] " IRAPUAM COSTA JUNIOR - PMDB/GO (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                    
#> [31,] " ITAMAR FRANCO - PL/MG (Ano de eleição: 1982)"                                                             
#> [32,] " IVAN BONATO - PFL/SC (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                              
#> [33,] " JAMIL HADDAD - PSB/RJ (Ano de eleição: 1982)"                                                             
#> [34,] " JARBAS PASSARINHO - PDS/PA (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                        
#> [35,] " JOÃO CALMON - PMDB/ES (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                             
#> [36,] " JOÃO CASTELO - PDS/MA (Ano de eleição: 1982)"                                                             
#> [37,] " JOÃO LOBO - PFL/PI (Ano de eleição: 1982)"                                                                
#> [38,] " JOÃO MENEZES - PFL/PA (Ano de eleição: 1982)"                                                             
#> [39,] " JORGE BORNHAUSEN - PFL / SC (Ano de eleição: 1982)"                                                       
#> [40,] " JOSÉ AGRIPINO - PFL/RN (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                            
#> [41,] " JOSÉ FOGAÇA - PMDB/RS (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                             
#> [42,] " JOSÉ IGNÁCIO FERREIRA - PMDB/ES (Ano de eleição: 1982) "                                                  
#> [43,] " JOSÉ PAULO BISOL - PSDB/RS (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                        
#> [44,] " JOSÉ RICHA - PSDB/PR (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                              
#> [45,] " JUTAHY MAGALHÃES - PMDB/BA (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                        
#> [46,] " LAVOISIER MAIA - PDS/RN (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                           
#> [47,] " LEITE CHAVES - PMDB/PR (Ano de eleição: 1982)"                                                            
#> [48,] " LEOPOLDO PERES - PMDB/AM (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                          
#> [49,] " LOUREMBERG NUNES ROCHA - PMDB/MT (Ano de eleição: 1986) "                                                 
#> [50,] " LOURIVAL BAPTISTA - PDS/SE (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                        
#> [51,] " LUIZ VIANA - PMDB/BA (Ano de eleição: 1982) "                                                             
#> [52,] " MANSUETO DE LAVOR - PMDB/PE (1986) "                                                                      
#> [53,] " MARCELO MIRANDA - PMDB/MS (Ano de eleição: 1982)"                                                         
#> [54,] " MARCIO LACERDA - PMDB/MT (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                          
#> [55,] " MARCO MACIEL - PFL/PE (Ano de eleição: 1982)"                                                             
#> [56,] " MARCONDES GADELHA - PFL/PB (Ano de eleição: 1982)"                                                        
#> [57,] " MÁRIO COVAS - PSDB/SP (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                             
#> [58,] " MÁRIO MAIA - PMDB/AC (Ano de eleição: 1982)"                                                              
#> [59,] " MAURÍCIO CORRÊA - PDT/DF (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                          
#> [60,] " MAURO BENEVIDES - PMDB/CE (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                         
#> [61,] " MAURO BORGES - PMD/GO (Ano de eleição: 1982)"                                                             
#> [62,] " MEIRA FILHO - PMDB/DF (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                             
#> [63,] " MENDES CANALE - PSDB/MS (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                           
#> [64,] " NABOR JÚNIOR - PMDB/AC (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                            
#> [65,] " NELSON CARNEIRO - PMDB/RJ (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                         
#> [66,] " NELSON WEDEKIN - PMDB/SC (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                          
#> [67,] " NEY MARANHÃO - PMB/PE (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                             
#> [68,] " NIVALDO MACHADO - PFL/PE (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                          
#> [69,] " ODACIR SOARES - PFL/RO (Ano de eleição: 1982)"                                                            
#> [70,] " OLAVO PIRES - PMDB/RO (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                             
#> [71,] " POMPEU DE SOUZA - PSDB/DF (Ano de eleição: 1986) "                                                        
#> [72,] " RACHID SALDANHA DERZI - PMDB/MS (Ano de eleição: 1986) "                                                  
#> [73,] " RAIMUNDO LIRA - PMDB/PB (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                           
#> [74,] " ROBERTO CAMPOS - PDS/MT (Ano de eleição: 1982)"                                                           
#> [75,] " RONALDO ARAGÃO - PMDB/RO (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                          
#> [76,] " RONAN TITO - PMDB/MG (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                              
#> [77,] " RUY BACELAR - PMDB/BA (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                             
#> [78,] " SEVERO GOMES - PMDB/SP (Ano de eleição: 1982)"                                                            
#> [79,] " TEOTÔNIO VILELA FILHO - PMDB/AL (Ano de eleição: 1986)"                                                   
#> [80,] " VIRGÍLIO TÁVORA - PDS/CE (Ano de eleição: 1982)"                                                          
#> [81,] " WILSON MARTINS - PMDB / MS (Ano de eleição: 1986)                                                        "
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The issue here is that the part that didn't work is actually just text (i.e., it's not a tag attribute or anything like that).  So, if you can isolate the div that contains just the text you want, and then grab the text, it works.  The text comes all in a single string, but each line you want is prefaced by some number of digits and a period.  So, if you split it on `\\d+\\.`, then it splits on the digits and period leaving everything else on a separate line.  The one complication is that the first string you get isn't needed, so you can just remove that one.